# Is there a software available that I can use to calculate outs?

Tags: equity

Simply put,

I don't wish to know the odds, or  the equity. I'm simply looking for a software than can help finding out outs given the hand and board information is fed into the program.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends. What do you want that feature for?

Comment: Want to have a software confirm my mental calculation for outs. Thought it was self explanatory.

Comment: You never said that in your original post. I don't think there's any of that. Still, it's pretty easy to check if you are right. You don't need to rely on a computer for everything

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a computer will only give you the final result of the calculation you do in your hand.
It's not like the computer gives you a perfect knowledge of the possible outs because it still doesn't know what are the face-down cards of each other player (same as you).
So it will only help you not make a human calculation mistake.

In my opinion, it's better to train you brain the hard way. After a while of thinking a certain way (poker-ish way), you brain will start finding these little "shortcuts" to find outs faster based on situations it already experienced before.